# Aligning two floated elements vertically

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstraps classes to float both elements and have the email address vertically align with the edit button.

I have added the style attribute "style='vertical-align: middle'" on the parent margin so that both elements can be aligned vertically and the email still doesn't align in the middle.

```
<div class='container'>
  <div class='row' >
    <div class='col-md-4 col-md-offset-4'>
      <label for='email-add'>Email Address </label>
      <div id='email-add'  style='vertical-align: middle' class='clearfix'>
        <span class='pull-left'> testemail@testemail.com </span>
        <span class='pull-right'> <button  class='btn btn-default edit '>Edit</button></span>
      </div>
    </div>    
  </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eldan88/x5jasdpv/

Comment: Start by looking up what elements vertical-align has an effect on.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/tjbaezid/f3d0kLh7/ is this what you looking for ??

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do exactly. Did you want the two span elements to be aligned vertically, with one above the other (it appears they already are), or horizontally, with both elements on the same row?

Comment: [This jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x5jasdpv/1/) might help visualize what is going on. Your label is inside the yellow bordered div, but your two span elements are inside the green bordered div. I'm still not sure what you are trying to do, but hopefully this visual will help.

Comment: Is there a reason you're still using `floats` as oppose to `display: inline-block;` It's much easier to use the display method so you don't have to worry about clearing floats. It also works well with the `vertical-align` property...

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I think I understand what you mean, but I think where you are going wrong is in your HTML structure.

Fiddle -

```css
label[for="email-add"]{
  display: inline-block;
    width: 80%;
}
.pull-right {
    float: right!important;
    margin: 10px;
}
.pull-left {
    float: left!important;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
   <div class='row' >
       <div class='col-md-4 col-md-offset-4'>
            
             <div id='email-add'  style='vertical-align: middle' class='clearfix'>
                  <label for='email-add'>Email Address </label>
                  <span class='pull-right'>  <button  class='btn btn-default edit '>Edit</button></span>
                 <span  class='pull-left'> testemail@testemail.com </span>
              
             </div>
       </div>

 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That looks pretty much the same as what is in the jsfiddle in the question http://jsfiddle.net/eldan88/x5jasdpv/.

Comment: Also, the `for` attribute of the `label` element must refer to a non-hidden form control. which means the `id='email-add'` should actually be on the `button`, not the div, so the HTML structure is still invalid. https://validator.w3.org/nu/

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of a more proper bootstrap style form. It only has the one label, input, and button, but you should be able to take this and modify it to add whatever other fields you need. Check out more info here http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='container'>
  <form>
    <div class='form-group'>
      <label for='email-add'>Email Address</label>
      <input type="text" id='email-add' class='form-control' value='testemail@testemail.com' />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <button class='btn btn-default edit'>Edit</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```